# Timers and Interrupts for Matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, signal-processing, interrupt

I would like to know if there are timer and interrupt functions available in Matlab. Do these exist?

I would like to run a sound clip through Matlab and convolve it with an impulse response. As I do this, I need interrupts to switch back and forth between methods. I am using Matlab to prototype an algorithm for a DSP. Thank you.

Comment: Can someone explain why I'm being down voted so much? I now know that there is a timer function in Matlab, but what about interrupts? There are no clear answers on interrupts and Matlab that I can find online. Thank you.

Comment: I think your question is completely valid. But it is not specific to programming. You should be describing what you want to achieve. You mention that `you want to switch back and forth between methods`. Does this mean that you want a small sample of the audio clip to be convolved using the first method and then doing the same using the second method? If so, you can do without timers and interrupts. Or you want to parallelize the program, where one core uses one method and the second core uses the other method?

Comment: Hi Lokesh, preferably I would like to parallelize the code, as that would make interrupts irrelevant. I know its possible in Matlab, but I don't think most Digital Signal Processors (like EZ Kit Lite) are multithreaded or multicore. So assuming that I can only execute code on one core and on one thread on a DSP, I wanted to be able to be model that in Matlab. I want to implement FFT convolution in one method, and standard convolution in the other; whereby if the FFT method is in execution, and a new sample comes in, an interrupt occurs and the new sample is processed in the other method.

Comment: Ok. that sounds reasonable. So, do you want to pipeline the task of data acquisition and data processing in MATLAB? How are you acquiring audio samples in MATLAB?

Comment: Hi Lokesh, sorry for responding so late. I have a saved audio file, a simple 15 second sample, that I am testing with. It is a bit hard to explain the exact method of processing, except that if I am in one method and a new sample comes in, I want to switch over to the other method, process this new sample, and then resume with where I left off in the other method. Is this possible? And this leads to another question: can I do sample by sample processing in Matlab? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, MATLAB cannot handle interrupts and timers. There are ways of using interrupts using `Data Acquisition Toolbox` as seen [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/ref/transfermode.html).

With audio samples in the hard drive, you will not be able to make use of interrupts. MATLAB does not allow you to pipeline the tasks. MATLAB allow does not allow the user to multithread, because bad things can happen. Instead, some of the operations in MATLAB are multithreaded and you get to use in your program. That said, you could finish processing with method 1, get data, and then switch to processing with method 2.

Sample by sample data processing is available in MATLAB. But with audio samples, it is better to use a [window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).